# Count Rows in Excel on condition<a>AND {condition<b> OR condition<c>}

Tags: excel, count, logic, formula

no matter how hard I reconfigure COUNTIF and COUNTIFS I can't get the output to work, here is a table example :

[image]

I cannot get a function that will count Where Severity = High AND (Customer !="" OR Case Info !="")

In the table example I should get a return of 5.

The closest I have got so far is with =COUNTIFS('8.2'!C:C,"*High*",'8.2'!A:A,"<>",'8.2'!B:B,"<>"), But that only returns 3.

What excel function could do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With COUNTIFS() you will need to do three:

```
=COUNTIFS(C:C,"High",A:A,"<>")+COUNTIFS(C:C,"High",B:B,"<>")-COUNTIFS(C:C,"High",A:A,"<>",B:B,"<>")
```

Or as XORLX showed:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(C:C,"High",A:A,{"<>","","<>"},B:B,{"","<>","<>"}))
```

But this requires that the cells be true blank, no formulas that return and empty string

[image]

---

SUMPRODUCT is slightly shorter but it requires that you specify the data range to avoid unnecessary iterations as it is an array type formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C17="high")*((A2:A17<>"")+(B2:B17<>"")-((A2:A17<>"")*(B2:B17<>""))))
```

Or this one by XORLX, who has forgotten more about excel formulas than I will ever know:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C1:C20="high")*((A1:A20<>"")+(B1:B20<>"")>0))
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify that your COUNTIFS solution is only valid if the blanks are "genuine" blanks, and not null strings (""). The SUMPRODUCT version is more robust in this respect. We can also use =SUM(COUNTIFS(C:C,"High",A:A,{"<>","","<>"},B:B,{"","<>","<>"})).

Comment: And you can abbreviate the SUMPRODUCT version to simply =SUMPRODUCT((C1:C17="high")*((A1:A17<>"")+(B1:B17<>"")>0))

Comment: @XORLX did not know the issue with countifs and true blank cells.  I get 7 instead of 5 with your countif formula.  Though, I can't believe I missed the SUMPRODUCT, got caught up in the logical expresion of the OP, I guess.

Comment: Hmmm. I get 5 using the dataset you posted. Perhaps you have some null strings in there yourself now?

Comment: Edit: you're correct. There was a non-breaking character after the last "<>" in the formula I posted, that's why. Can't seem to remove it.

Comment: @XORLX I was able to remove it and got the `5`